# Invalid hook call, как правильно использовать хук в данном случаи?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hook

Имеется такой компонент

```
import PokemonItem from './../PokemonItem';

function PokemonList() {

    const [pokemons, setPokemons] = useState({
        pokemonList: [],
        loading: true,
    }); 

    useEffect(()=>{
        fetch('https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/')
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then(body => {
            setPokemons({
                pokemonList: body.results,
                loading: false,
            })

        })
    }, [])




    let pokemonItems = pokemons.pokemonList.map((pokemon, index) => {
        return <PokemonItem name={pokemon.name} key={index} url={pokemon.url} />
    })


    return(
        <div className="pokemon-list">
            {pokemonItems}
        </div>
    )
}
```

Я получаю данные с сервера, дальше создаю компоненты `<PokemonItem url={pokemon.url} />`, где в `props` передаю ссылку для получения полной информации на каждый элемент списка.

В компоненте `<PokemonItem />`, я создаю хук с состоянием для каждого элемента списка:

```
function PokemonItem(props) {



    const [pokemon, setPokemon] = useState({
        pokemonInfo: [],
        loading: true,
    }); 




    return(
        <li className="pokemon-item">
            <div className="pokemon-item__profile">
                <img src="" alt="" className="pokemon-item__sprite"/>
                <span className="pokemon-item__name">
                    {props.name}
                </span>
            </div>
        </li>
    )
}
```

Но получаю такую ошибку:

> Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body
>   of a function component. This could happen for one of the following
>   reasons:
>   1. You might have mismatching versions of React and the renderer (such as React DOM)
>   2. You might be breaking the Rules of Hooks
>   3. You might have more than one copy of React in the same app See https://fb.me/react-invalid-hook-call for tips about how to debug and
>   fix this problem.

Вроде нескольких копий нет, правил хуков тоже не нарушал, и версии, нормальные, раз крашиться начало именно в этом компоненте, до этого хуки работали. В чем может быть проблема?

UPD:

При удалении данного кода из компонента PokemonItem, приложение начинает работать. Т.е. проблема в данном куске кода, непонятно почему

```
const [pokemonq, setPokemon] = useState({
    pokemonInfo: [],
    loading: true,
});
```

Comment: напиши полностью код компонента. нет import React from 'react'

Comment: @СергейПетрашко, там есть все необходимые импорты, обновил так же реакт до последней вверсии, не помогло, та же ошибка...

Comment: Вопрос! А с какой целью добавлен этот код в компоненте PokemonItem?
`const [pokemonq, setPokemon] = useState({
    pokemonInfo: [],
    loading: true,
});` Просто я не вижу дальнейшего использования состояния.